# ¿How to access Product attributes in a HABM association in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Product` table and a `'color_attributes'` table that relate through a HABM association in the table `color_attributes_products`.

When I try to access `Product.where(id: 1).color_attributes` I get an error:

```
 `undefined method `color_attributes' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000010bc17058>`
```

¿How am I supposed to access the colors of the product in my views?

**Colors Attributes table:**

```
  create_table "color_attributes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.string "color_name"
    t.integer "hex"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**Association table**

```
create_table "color_attributes_products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "color_attribute_id"
  end
```

**Products table:**

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "tipo"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "marked"
    t.json "images"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "url"
    t.decimal "costprice", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.integer "size"
    t.decimal "ancho", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.decimal "alto", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.decimal "markedprice", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "extra_for"
    t.boolean "featured"
    t.string "box_type"
    t.integer "order"
    t.string "options"
    t.integer "printing_type"
    t.integer "max_printing_colors"
    t.text "available_colors", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["active"], name: "index_products_on_active"
    t.index ["extra_for"], name: "index_products_on_extra_for"
    t.index ["price"], name: "index_products_on_price"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_products_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["tipo"], name: "index_products_on_tipo"
  end
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`Product.where(...)` always return an ActiveRecord collection - you'll want to use `find` if you want to work with a single record, as in:

```
Product.find(1).color_attributes
```